# VBA Script to quickprint jpg without dialog

Tags: printing, outlook, jpeg

i found this script, which prints attachments of outlook emails automatically.

unfortunately Office opens a picture print dialog every time for jpg and other pictures. This interrupts the process! Script is useless then.

Can somebody please modify this script, so that pictures are quickprinted without any dialog in between?

THANKS!

```
Sub AttachementAutoPrint(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
  'Updated by Extendoffice 20230223
   Dim xFS As FileSystemObject
   Dim xTempFolder As String
   Dim xAtt As Attachment
   Dim xShell As Object
   Dim xFolder As Object, xFolderItem As Object
   Dim xFileName As String
   On Error GoTo xError
   If Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
   Set xFS = New FileSystemObject
   xTempFolder = xFS.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
   xTempFolder = xTempFolder & "\ATMP" & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmddhhmmss")
   If Not xFS.FolderExists(xTempFolder) Then
     MkDir (xTempFolder)
   End If
   Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   Set xFolder = xShell.NameSpace(0)
   For Each xAtt In Item.Attachments
     If IsEmbeddedAttachment(xAtt) = False Then
   xFileName = xTempFolder & "\" & xAtt.FileName
   xAtt.SaveAsFile (xFileName)
   Set xFolderItem = xFolder.ParseName(xFileName)
   xFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")
 End If
Next xAtt
   Set xFS = Nothing
   Set xFolder = Nothing
   Set xFolderItem = Nothing
   Set xShell = Nothing
xError:
  If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, , "Kutools for Outlook"
    Err.Clear
  End If
Exit Sub
End Sub

Function IsEmbeddedAttachment(Attach As Attachment)
Dim xItem As MailItem
Dim xCid As String
Dim xID As String
Dim xHtml As String
On Error Resume Next
IsEmbeddedAttachment = False
Set xItem = Attach.Parent
If xItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then Exit Function
xCid = ""
xCid = Attach.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")
If xCid <> "" Then
    xHtml = xItem.HTMLBody
    xID = "cid:" & xCid
    If InStr(xHtml, xID) > 0 Then
        IsEmbeddedAttachment = True
    End If
End If
End Function
```